# What configuration will let vim show the buffer/filename in the status line even when only one buffer/file is open?

Tags: vim

When I have more one one file open in vim (using split-screen), each <strike>command</strike>status line (the last line in the window) looks like this:

```
filename.txt                           73,1            4%
```

That's the filename on the left, with the ruler position and percentage through the file on the right (via `:set ruler`).

However, when I only have one buffer open, the status line looks like:

```
                                       73,1            4%
```

How can I show the filename in all circumstances, even when there is only one file open?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's the status line (`:help status-line`). To enable it when you only have one window, add to your .vimrc:

```
set laststatus=2
```

Comment: Ah, I thought it was called the command line because that's the reference that came up with `:help ruler` -- the compiler option `cmdline_info` needs to be enabled.  Question text edited.  And thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use `:set title` which sets filename with path in title bar of your console window. The title changes automatically when the filename changes. To enable it permanently add it to your `.vimrc`

Answer (score 2):

I actually think the very bottom line in vim is called "ruler", since it's enabled by ":set ruler".

The format of the ruler could be customized, following the same syntax of "statusline", just as the vim help page says:

[image: Vim help page for "rulerformat"]

At last, here is a good tutorial to the vim "statusline", including adding a file name into it: [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way -- Status Lines](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/17.html)

Comment: and how I let vim show the buffer filename  in rulerformat ?

Comment: @Sérgio `:set laststatus=2` will do the trick for you.

Comment: :set laststatus=2 show status one line above of status line, I prefer :set title